# numpy return indices using multiple conditions of UNKNOWN number

Tags: numpy

Consider two arrays (X and Y), X is a 2D data array (grayscale image), and Y is an **array of conditions** where array X needs to be filtered based on, as follows:

```
X = np.array([[0,0,0,0,4], [0,1,1,2,3], [1,1,2,2,0], [0,0,2,2,3], [0,0,0,0,0]])
Y = np.array([1,2,3])

X:
[[0 0 0 0 4]
 [0 1 1 2 3]
 [1 1 2 2 0]
 [0 0 2 2 3]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
Y:
[1 2 3]
```

I need to select the elements/indices of array X based on the values in array Y, such that:

```
Z = np.argwhere((X == Y[0]) | (X == Y[1]) | (X == Y[2]))
Z:
[[1 1]
 [1 2]
 [1 3]
 [1 4]
 [2 0]
 [2 1]
 [2 2]
 [2 3]
 [3 2]
 [3 3]
 [3 4]]
```

This can be done using a loop over the items of array Y, is there a numpy function to achieve this?

It is also achievable using multiple conditions in a `np.argwhere` function, however, the number of conditions (length of array Y ) is unknown beforhand.

Thanks

Comment: `argwhere` just does `np.transpose(np.where(cond))`. That is, it turns the tuple of arrays produced by `np.where/nonzero` into a 2d array.  The tuple form can be used as an index directly (for an array like `X`).  The `argwhere` version has to either iterate by row, or use the columns as index arrays (duplicating the `nonzero` indexing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to prepare the correct mask. For that, use [`numpy.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
np.isin(X, Y)
```

You'll get a boolean mask as a result, of the same shape `X` has.  Now you can get the indices using an appropriate method.

Comment: If `Y` isn't too large `isin` actually uses a repeated `|`, a generalization of the OP.  Look at its code.